# Excel SSIS and SQL server

Tags: ssis

I want to develop an automation in SSIS.

Problem statement :

I have an excel sheet which has a single column.

Based on the values in that column (will be included as a search parameter in the SQL query) I need to fetch 2 or more columns from SQL server database 
The results are to be stored in the same Excel sheet against the data obtained for that particular column.

I already have an excel macro for the same. But, now I want to develop a package for the same.

Please guide me through the necessary steps.

I will also keep trying to obtain the solution

Comment: If you have an Excel macro doing the job already, and the input and output are coming from Excel, why do you want to build an SSIS package?

Comment: Just to check whether this requirement will be satisfied in BIDS

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an Excel Source and link it to your file
2. use a lookup component to perform a SQL select to obtain the missing data
3. Create an Excel destination to save your target data